# Grunt - FTP check changes and download/upload newer

Tags: plugins, ftp, gruntjs, last-modified

I use different computers for creating web app and now I started to learn how to use [Gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com).

Now I need some plugin which on default action checks by (S)FTP if on the server are any changes (by modification date) and if so, downloads the changed files to the project folder. Or it may just be combination of some plugins.

What do you recommend me?

Answer (score 0):

What you have described is basically how Git works! I don't think that Grunt can do that, and even if it did it's not the best use scenario.

Start with creating a private repository on [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) put your code there and then use [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) to download your latest changes of your code

If you feel more curious check [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) so that every time you push your latest changes they are immediately put in a FTP folder so that every one can access it.

Comment: Can you go to details on how do I put it all together?
Is it Linux compatible or I need Wine?
I'm beginner. Thx